# How to keep Glasses on when Breastfeeding/Feeding

Tags: newborn, breastfeeding

When my partner is feeding the baby, her glasses slip down because she's looking down at the baby, and she has both hands full, so she can't push them up. I'm happy to push them back on when I'm there, but I was wondering if there was any advice from bespectacled mothers on how to handle this problem.

Comment: Croakies? http://croakies.com/

Comment: Any reason not to wear her contact lenses?

Comment: With experience, she will/should be able to breastfeed practically hands-free. In fact, she'll be able to manage to eat, cook, type, etc. -- all while breastfeeding.

Comment: Doesn't have any. Doesn't wear them generally.

Comment: @Swati but, by the time that experience arrives, the babies learn to grab things... such as one's glasses. B-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bought some small [braiding rubber bands](http://www.hairqueen.com/ruba30.html) (which you can find in the "ethnic hair" section of any pharmacy next to hair relaxer) and wrapped a couple around the ends of my wife's glasses [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMoml.jpg).  She says they stay up now.

This type of rubber band is good because it doesn't fall apart after a few months and doesn't grab at hair the way a regular rubber band does.

Comment: You're just wrapping them around the end of the ear pieces? That's a great idea.

Comment: You're right, it's unclear.  I do mean wrapping them around just the ends, not making a poor-man's croakie.

Answer (score 8):

I know this hardly seems like an answer at all, but better fitting glasses are probably your best option. Mom likely doesn't even need new glasses, but maybe just an adjustment for a better fit around the ears.

Good luck!